# ExtJS4 and place some elements inside panel

Tags: extjs4

Can't set panel properties to place properly some elements on the panel.

I don't want to use "height" property but I can't find
a proper way how to do it. On the second tabpanel side
(I mean this one with gridpamel and toolbar) I have to
set all the area for grid but without this toolbar. So
toolbar should be the constant on this panel and grid
should fill the rest of space. I tried to set 
"layout: 'fit'" for panel but this remove tabpanel. When
I set the same layout for gridpanel, this gridpanel display
e.g.two lines and toolbar right under it.

```
=======================================
|  Window                             |
|=====================================|
|                                     |
|---------\----------\  TabPAnel      |
|    1    |     2    |                |
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|                                     |
|       gridpanel                     |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|
|    toolbar                          |
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|  dockeditems: toolbar               |
|                                     |
=======================================

window
    tabpanel
        panel
            form
                textfields
                ... 5
                textfield
                gridpanel
                toolbar
        panel
            gridpanel
            toolbar  
    toolbar (dockeditems)
```

Can't find how to do it, could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flex  and remove the height property if assigned in the grid panel

```
flex:1
```

And remove the height property from the toolbar

or use the container and place the grid panel in one contaier and toolbar and docked items in the other container